# Display non-critical notifications when totem is playing video

Tags: notification, notify-osd, totem

When I'm watching videos in Totem, only critical notifications are displayed. To me, it is more important to get these notifications when I'm watching a video in full screen, because then there is nothing else to indicate that something has happened. I currently have to switch back and forth in order to see if I have been notified of something. It seems very unnecessary.

I need to display all notifications. Is this configurable, or how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, this is not configurable. There is a proposed [compatibility fix](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#totem) that would make this an option, but it hasn't been implemented.